# Wireshark / Fiddler not displaying traffic through C# Webclient when using proxy

Tags: c#, webclient, fiddler, wireshark

I'm currently building an application that extends a company-wide internal website. The application makes the same calls as the Browser would do when surfing on that website - it just submits some forms using HTTP-POST.

I need to use our company proxy IP in order to get an authorized request up and running through my application.

```
_webclient = new WebClient();
_webclient.Proxy = new WebProxy("A.B.C.D:8080", false, new string[0], CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);
_webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

(Note: The IP is not a local proxy, so therefore Wireshark / Fiddler should be able to capture it).

When running my application, i get the correct response from the server, but i'm not able to see any traffic through wireshark / fiddler.

```
var response = _webclient.UploadString("http://myFancyurl/foo.php", "POST", "some=data&sendTo=theServer");
// response is now "<html>......"
```

Any ideas what i did wrong either using the proxy or regarding wireshark / Fiddler?

Comment: What happens if you browse http://myFancyurl/foo.php in IE ? Is gateway configured on Fiddler. Usually it picks network setting as per configuration in IE.

Comment: It's strange that you don't see traffic in WireShark. Fiddler is a proxy, not a sniffer, so you should set proxy address to localhost:fiddler_port to use it.